# c# update/insert from datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Whenever the code is executed, it always return that the ID value is not supplied that will cause an error. Would someone please show me where is my error? In some queries there is also `sqlcommand.Parameters.Clear();` which is not included in this code.

The @ID should be pointing to the first column in the `datagridview`, where I can also set the match with the ID (primary key) in the table via SQL Management.

```
using (SqlCommand InsUpd = new SqlCommand(
            @"IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Bokfuppg WHERE dbo.Bokfuppg.ID = @ID)
            UPDATE dbo.bokfuppg
            SET fnr = @Fnr, kto = @Kto, Ukto = @Ukto, avd = @Avd, prod = @Prod, proj = @Proj, ant = @Ant, bel = @Bel, Text = @Text, vbel = @Vbel, period = @Period
            WHERE dbo.Bokfuppg.ID = @ID
            ELSE
            INSERT INTO dbo.bokfuppg(Fnr, Kto, Ukto, Avd, Prod, Proj, ant, bel, text, vbel, period) VALUES(@Fnr, @Kto, @Ukto, @Avd, @Prod, @Proj, @Ant, @Bel, @Text, @Vbel, @Period)", con))

        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
                InsUpd.Transaction = tr;

                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Fnr", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Kto", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Ukto", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Avd", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Prod", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Proj", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Ant", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Bel", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Vbel", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                InsUpd.Parameters.Add("@Period", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridViewBokfuppg.Rows)
                {

                    InsUpd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = item.Cells[0].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Fnr"].Value = textBox1.Text;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Kto"].Value = item.Cells[1].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Ukto"].Value = item.Cells[2].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Avd"].Value = item.Cells[3].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Prod"].Value = item.Cells[4].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Proj"].Value = item.Cells[5].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Ant"].Value = item.Cells[6].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Bel"].Value = item.Cells[7].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Text"].Value = item.Cells[8].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Vbel"].Value = item.Cells[9].Value;
                    InsUpd.Parameters["@Period"].Value = item.Cells[10].Value;
                    InsUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                tr.Commit();
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");`
```

Comment: Convert it to stored procedure and try

Comment: Thank you, but for this specific purpose I found another model to use, but you suggestion led me to read more abount stored procedure, which definitly will become valuable in the future.